# How to change the color of a button using WM_CTLCOLORBTN?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am pretty new to C++ and the Windows API.

I cannot figure out how to change the background color of a button using `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` while simultaneously having a bitmap on the button. When I try to do this, the program crashes.

I have created a button like this:

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
HWND hbutton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 15, 202.5, 96.5, 72.5, hWnd, (HMENU)301, hInstance, NULL);
```

In the `WndProc` function, I have written:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
   switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam) -> code) 
   {
      MessageBox(hWnd, L"made it inside of the switch statement", L"Debug", 1);
   }
```

I have also tried:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
   LPNMHDR button = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
   if(button->idfrom == 301 && button->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
   {
   }
```

In addition, I have tried:

```
case CDDS_PREERASE:
   LPNMHDR button = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
   if(button->idfrom == 301 && button->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
   {
   }
```

Furthermore, I have tried:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
   MessageBox(hWnd, L"Code in wm_notify got ran", L"Debug", 1);
```

The code above does not cause a message box to appear, so it is assumed to have never ran.

All of these methods have resulted in the program crashing.

I have seen in some other posts people putting their code inside of `WM_NOTIFY`, but that results in the code not running at all.

Would anyone happen to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Being new to c++ basically means having to spend 5+ years learning the language.

Comment: Why aren't you using a debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure MessageBox works inside WndProc.

Comment: The code mixes up the handling of WM_NOTIFY and WM_CTLCOLORBTN.  The latter doesn't pass LPNMHDR so that's doomed to fail.  Turn on the BS_OWNERDRAW style when you create the button and handle the WM_DRAWITEM message to implement it.

Comment: use `OutputDebugString` to trace like that. YOu can place that call anywhere. The ouput will appear in visual studio window in running in VS. Elsewhere you need a tool like dbgview

Comment: In what way did it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to specify an `HINSTANCE` when creating a system-defined window class. So, you can set the `hInstance` parameter to `NULL`.

Second, all of the message handlers you have shown are wrong:

- The `lParam` parameter of the `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` message is an `HWND` window handle (of the button), not an `LPNMHDR` struct pointer.  `NMHDR` structs are used only in `WM_NOTIFY` messages.
- `CDDS_PREERASE` is not a window message.  It is the value of a drawing stage used by the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` message.  `CDDS_PREERASE` has a numeric value of 3, which is the same value as the `WM_MOVE` window message, whose `lParam` contains X/Y coordinates, not an `LPNMHDR` pointer.
- Most button notifications are delivered to a button's parent window using `WM_COMMAND` messages. There are only 3 button notifications that are delivered to the parent window using `WM_NOTIFY` messages - `BCN_DROPDOWN`, `BCN_HOTITEMCHANGE`, and `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`. The first 2 don't apply to your button example.  The 3rd one applies only if your app has [Comctl32.dll v6 enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview), in which case the `lParam` parameter is an `LPNMCUSTOMDRAW` struct pointer, not an `LPNMHDR` pointer.

Now then, the [`WM_CTLCOLORBTN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorbtn) documentation says:

> Parameters
>
> wParam
> An HDC that specifies the handle to the display context for the button.
>
> lParam
> An HWND that specifies the handle to the button.
>
> Return value
>
> If an application processes this message, it must return a handle to a brush. The system uses the brush to paint the background of the button.

So, try something more like this instead:

```
HWND hButton = NULL;
HBRUSH hButtonBkg = NULL;

...

case WM_CREATE: {
    ...
    hButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 15, 202.5, 96.5, 72.5, hWnd, (HMENU)301, hInstance, NULL);
    hButtonBkg = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(...)); // <-- whatever color you want
    ...
    break;
}

case WM_DESTROY: {
    DeleteObject(hButtonBkg);
    break;
}

case WM_CTLCOLORBTN: {
    if (hButton == (HWND)lParam) {
        HDC hdc = (HDC) wParam;
        // configure hdc as needed...
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(...)); // <-- whatever color you want
        return (LRESULT) hButtonBkg;
    }
    break;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN: {
    if (hButton == (HWND)lParam) {
        HDC hdc = (HDC) wParam;
        // configure hdc as needed...
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(...));    // <-- whatever color you want
        SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(...)); // <-- whatever color you want
        return (LRESULT) GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
    }
    break;
}
```

However, the `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` documentation also says:

> However, only owner-drawn buttons respond to the parent window processing this message.
>
> ...
>
> By default, the `DefWindowProc` function selects the default system colors for the button. **Buttons with the `BS_PUSHBUTTON`, `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`, or `BS_PUSHLIKE` styles do not use the returned brush. Buttons with these styles are always drawn with the default system colors.** Drawing push buttons requires several different brushes - face, highlight, and shadow - but the `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` message allows only one brush to be returned. **To provide a custom appearance for push buttons, use an owner-drawn button.** For more information, see [Creating Owner-Drawn Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/user-controls-intro).

So, you should add the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style to your button, in which case you will need to handle the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem) message instead to custom-draw the button how you want.